# How do I compare my input to my state array, to prevent duplicate INPUT

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. This is a simple To Do list, that cannot accept duplicate "tasks" on the list. I have no idea on how to do this.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tasks: [
        "Don't allow empty tasks",
        "Add strikethrough style to checked off tasks",
        "Don't allow duplicate tasks",
        "Give it some style ✨",
        "Let users delete tasks"
      ]
    };
  }
```

this is the table ^^

```
handleClick() {
  
    if (this.state.inputValue === "") {
      alert("Cannot accept Blank Entry");
    } else {
      this.props.onAdd(this.state.inputValue);
      this.setState({ inputValue: "" });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Don't put code as images. Please read guidelines and help us to help you.

Comment: Add else if on second block

Comment: Please show the array

Comment: I have added the array

Comment: @LeandroBardelli remember to give folks the links to our guidelines when telling them to read them. In this case, the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) =)

Comment: what's the implementation of `this.props.onAdd`? You can probably modify that function to not add an item if it already exists in the list of todos.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you are right. And I will retract the vote

Comment: @Nathan how exactly do I check if the item exists on the list of Todos?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, you need to check what's in the current value of `tasks`, something like this:

```
handleClick() {
  if (this.state.inputValue === "") {
    alert("Cannot accept Blank Entry");
  } else if (this.state.tasks.includes(this.state.inputValue)) {
    alert("Task already exists");
  } else {
    this.props.onAdd(this.state.inputValue);
    this.setState({ inputValue: "" });
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that, it didn't work that way

Comment: What exactly happened when it “didn’t work”? Did you get an error message? Did the includes check fail? You _must_ check for inclusion somehow, so if it didn’t work, something else is going wrong that you need to handle.